SMD Component Identification 6 pin
I am having a difficult time trying to identify the following 6 pin SMD component:


Please post dimensions and package information

Probably a 30V ~1A 1.4MHz step-down converter made by Tech Public, Rychip or JSMICRO (there are likely more). The naming of these suggests that these are clones of the MP2359 by MPS, but the MPS version has different markings.

(Source: Rychip datasheet)

(JSMSEMI version, source: lcsc.com)

Hmm, when I first looked at the picture in the question thought the marking code started GB, but on looking at the zoomed in picture the marking code might start with CB. The picture in the question is currently a bit blurry so not entirely sure what the marking code is.

@ChesterGillon I checked again and Its definely GBG5D
